# How do i get Android Studio's Lint to alert me about calls that don't meet minSDK?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-lint

I have set the min sdk version in `build.gradle` as `minSdkVersion 8` (I set it low so it was easy to find an API that wasn't added yet). but when I run `Analyze->Inspect Code...` it doesn't show the call to the above-8 API in the errors. How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to sync the gradle changes. Then Lint sees the issues.